# SPServices Add values to People picker field in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spservices

How can I add or update people picker field in SharePoint list/library using SPServices

I tried to post the account ID it did not worked tried display name it did not worked, do you know what is the format acceptable for people picker field.

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    batchCmd: "New",
    listName: "PersonnelRecord",
    valuepairs: [["EmployeePickerField",PostDisplayName], ["LastName",PostLastName],],
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set person field with user id like this snippet (get current user id and set)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var thisUserID = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "ID",
    debug: false
});
var title='test'
$().SPServices({
   weburl: "http://sp/sites/dev/",
   operation: "UpdateListItems",
   async: true,
   batchCmd: "New",
   listName: "TestList1",
   valuepairs: [["Title",title],["User",thisUserID]],
   completefunc: function(xData,Status){}
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to add the current user

Comment: I want to add any users if I enter his email in the email box

Comment: Or do you know how to get the UserId based on email ID ? so that I query the ID and than process add/update

Comment: @Jerry, your soln was not working. in my case. i am using a  separate functional inside content editor web part and called the custom function just before presaveaction() . i want to access the user , who is added/modified in the client ppl picker control field in my editform.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Format to update people picker field from spservice is "useridfromuserinfolist;#domain\username"

```
e.g "7;#microsoftdomain\m3456"
```

If you want to read it from people picker field on page/html then you can use below

```
var userLoginName = $('span.assest_pp').find('span.ms-entity-resolved div').attr("key"); // this will return you in format "domain\username"

var thisUserID = "-1;#" + userLoginName ; // here assuming we don't know the userid stored in UserInfoList.

Your value Pair should look like

 valuepairs: [["Title",title],["User",thisUserID]],
```

JFYI...Depending on SP2010 or SP 2013, below line will return different data but it will still work if you setting in above format.

```
$('span.assest_pp').find('span.ms-entity-resolved div').attr("key")

i:0#.w|domain\username - SP 2013
domain\username - SP 2010
```

Hope this helps..happy coding...!!!

Comment: you question is "How can I add or update people picker field in SharePoint list/library using SPServices"....above explain that only and if you user information is coming from AD...just focus getting is loginname and update in format "-1;#domain\username"..it should work.

Comment: I passed something like this: var UserDetail = "-1;#Username"; and it did not worked I have 2010 SharePoint

Comment: What is the acceptable format of data for UserPicker field in a SharePoint list using SPServices

Comment: Please paste you whole updated code, the format you are trying is correct....are you also passing domain name ?

Comment: Yes I did pass the domain name it did not worked.

Comment: The only value it accept is the user id for example when I paste 3455 which is a user id it accept it

Comment: Do you know how to get userid of user using SPServices ?